# issue with the closing the app

Tags: android

i am working on an android project and i have a little problem about closing problem.my question is i want to use text to speech before closing the app.but it just closes and not talks how can i fix this situation.this is the code i have

```
    if (item.getTitle()== "ExitItem"){

            say("Bye Master,May The Force Be With You");

                finish();
```

i am sure this is very easy but because of the late hours i can not think correctly anymore :DD anyway have a good day

```
    public void say(String text2say){
    talker.speak(text2say, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

@Override
    public void onInit(int status) {

}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (talker != null) {
        talker.stop();
        talker.shutdown();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve the problem completely and you've only posted a bit of the code, but the first thing I notice is that you're using `==` to compare strings which is a bad practice.

Try changing it to:

```
if (item.getTitle().equals("ExitItem") {
```

Also, if the `say` method is executed asynchronously then `finish()` would likely get called and executed before the `say` method has a chance to do anything.

**Edit:** Since it is done async you will want to use onUtteranceCompleted to catch when the text to speech phrase has been said.

```
TextToSpeech tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new OnInitListener() {

 @Override
 public void onInit(int status) {

    mTts.setOnUtteranceCompletedListener(new OnUtteranceCompletedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onUtteranceCompleted(String utteranceId) {

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    finish();
                }
            });
        }
    });

 }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much for your information.i changed the if statemennts.sorry i don't get it,i mean we have a process priority with java code you know upper code executes first in same class or method.so do i have to indicate or write something to fix the asynchronousization problem??

Comment: If the `say` method is done async, like in an `AsyncTask` you would need to execute the `finish` call in [onPostExecute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute(Result)). Can you post more of the code? The enclosing function for the code above and the `say` method would be helpful.

Comment: code is enlosed with the onOptionsItemSelected method.and say method is updated

Comment: what is mTts you haven't defined it and i can't implement this block to the onOptionsItemSelected method

Answer (score 0):

**onUtteranceCompleted** and **OnUtteranceProgress** will help you track the progress of your call. Place finish() accordingly.

Comment: i am sorry i did now understand the answer.i mean how can unterrenceprogress help me.can you be more specific??

Comment: Looks like you found the implementation. Good Luck!!